# CSS screen resolution

Tags: html, css, size, screen, resolution

I'm having an issue with screen resolution. My website is not centered properly on other computer screens. How do I code my stylesheet so that my website is centered no matter what computer screen it is on?

Answer (score 1):

Give your container a width and auto left/right margin.

```
.container {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

**note:** don't have a fixed position

Answer (score 0):

```
element{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: «any type of block (block, inline-block, etc)»
}
```

The code above should center any element horizontally in respect to it's parent element.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to your problem:

```
div{
      position:absolute;
      top:500px;
      margin-left:-50px;
      left:50%;
      width:100px;
      border:1px solid #000000;
      height:100px;
    }
```